# How to properly handle empty, missed, default form values?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-app-engine

I have html form, where it is possible that:

(1) user input's nothing, for ex., in case with text input field;

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="first-name" name="first-name">
```

(2) user leaves default empty value, like with select:

```
<select id="prof-area" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
```

(3) user leaves empty value, like with multiple options select:

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="reason" name="reason" class="input-xlarge">
    <option value="001">reason001</option>
    <option value="002">reason002</option>
```

In each case on GAE side I should understand that this is empty value.

```
first_name = None
if self.request.get('first-name'):
    first_name = self.request.get('first-name')
```

works well with case (1).

```
prof_area = None
if self.request.get('prof-area') and self.request.get('prof-area') !='0':
    prof_area = self.request.get('prof-area')
```

should work for case (2), but doesn't look well. Is there any better way to handle the same?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this work unless you have added the `required=True` argument. If you put an entity missing some property, GAE create or update the entity with the property missed empty. See this [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/propertyclass#Property)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a name parameter for your prof-area field which is prob why you are't seeing data at the server.

Anyways, try this ...

At the client, just put an empty string in your empty select option, like this:

```
<select id="prof-area" name="prof-area" class="input-xlarge">
  <option value="" selected="selected"> -- select -- </option>
</select
```

then at the server, first grab all the values into local variables - makes it easier for others to see whats going on ...

```
first_name = self.request.get('first_name')
prof_area = self.request.get('prof-area')
reason = self.request.get('reason')
```

you can then check each param in turn ...

```
if first_name:
  # do something with first_name

if prof_area:
  # do something with prof_area

if reason:
  # do something with reason
```